# fuction always return null pl-sql

Tags: plsql

good morning everyone
i write this code to check for record in database and return error or null
but the problem its always return 
when i test in database it refused to check if statement and go directly to exception

```
 begin

l_CURRENT_DATE := P_FROM_DATE;
select P_TO_DATE - P_FROM_DATE into l_DAY_COUNT from dual;

--   while l_CURRENT_DATE between P_FROM_DATE and P_TO_DATE loop
for i in 0 .. l_DAY_COUNT loop
  --  l_CURRENT_DATE := P_FROM_DATE + i;

  select to_number(to_char(l_CURRENT_DATE, 'd'))
    into l_DAY_NUMBER
    from dual;

  -------------------------------------
  if l_DAY_NUMBER = 1 and P_DAY1 = 1 then

    select 1
      into l_DUMMY
      from dual
     where exists (select *
              from PBG_PARK_BOOKING
             where BOOKING_DATE = l_CURRENT_DATE
               and NUM1 = P_PARK
               and FROM_TIME = P_FROM_TIME
               and TO_TIME = P_TO_TIME);

    if l_DUMMY is not null then
      return('PBG-ERROR410:Please Inform there is an Conflict with other Resevation..');
    end if;
  end if;

  l_DUMMY := '';

  --------------------------------------
  if l_DAY_NUMBER = 2 and P_DAY2 = 2 then

    select 1
      into l_DUMMY
      from dual
     where exists (select *
              from PBG_PARK_BOOKING
             where BOOKING_DATE = l_CURRENT_DATE
               and NUM1 = P_PARK
               and FROM_TIME = P_FROM_TIME
               and TO_TIME = P_TO_TIME);

    if l_DUMMY is not null then
      return('PBG-ERROR410:Please Inform there is an Conflict with other Resevation..');
    end if;
  end if;

  l_DUMMY := '';


end loop
exception
  when no_data_found then
  return null;

end ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You posted incomplete code; there are some variables (or, possibly, parameters) used which are never declared (such as `P_TO_DATE`, `P_FROM_DATE`, etc.).

Anyway: saying that code "refuses" to check the `IF` statement (I believe you meant to say that it actually *executes* `IF`, but fails on `SELECT` within) and goes directly to exception handling section means that `SELECT` returned *nothing* (i.e. raised `NO_DATA_FOUND`).

If you don't want that to happen, make sure that `SELECT` returns *something*.

On the other hand, seeing that you wrote a loop, maybe you wanted to check all `FOR LOOP` indexes, i.e. if it fails on the first one, fine - go check the second one, and so forth.

If that's so, you should enclose code within the loop into its own `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block:

```
for i in 0 .. l_day_count loop
  -- inner BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block starts here ...
  begin
    l_day_number := to_number(to_char(...));

    if l_day_number = 1 ...
       select ... into l_dummy ...
    end if;

    if l_day_number = 2 ...
       select ... into l_dummy ...
    end if;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      null;     --> don't RETURN null; not just yet, if you want to check all FOR loop indexes
  end;
  -- ... and ends here
end loop;
```